Odoo 15: Contacts list filter by current user
In Contacts App.
Form create new contact I added an assignee field to assign contact to user
class Partner(models.Model):
    _name = 'res.partner'
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    assignee_ids = fields.Many2many(
        'res.users',
        relation='contacts_contact_user_rel',
        column1='contact_id',
        column2='user_id',
        string='Assignees',
        default=lambda self: not self.env.user.share and self.env.user,
        context={'active_test': False},
        tracking=True
    )

I create an inherit form view:
    <record id="res_contact_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.contact.view.form</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//span[@name='address_name']" position="before">
                <field name="assignee_ids" widget="many2many_avatar_user" domain="[('share', '=', False)]"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

I want to when view type is kanban or list, contacts will be filter by assingee_ids match to current user
How I can do that? Please help me.

In Contacts (res.partner) there are user_id and user_ids fields. You can show them in your form view and fill them out.
About grouping, you can not group records by a many-to-many field but you can do this by a many-to-one field and you can do this by user_id field in res.partner.

Hi Hamid Mirzapour, I want to one contact can be assign to many user. But when I use user_ids field I have problem when I add user and save, Assigned users are renamed to the contact name

You are right. It might Odoo does something with this user_ids field that happens.
I think you should create another one2any field related to user and use it instead user_ids field.

I create a field assignee_ids = fields.Many2many('res.users', string='Assignees') but I don't know how to filter data. Can you help me?

By the filter, if you mean filter in the search view, you cannot filter or group records based on a many2many or one2many or computed (not stored) field.
But if you mean set domain based on a many2many or one2many field, you can do this.

Can we set domain on python? I tried inherit base.view_partner_tree and set attribute domain for tree bug I got an error when upgrade app. It seems we can't set domain attribute for element tree
